# Swift: Trying to get coordinates, but don't know how to call locationManager() function

Tags: swift, location, core-location, cllocation

I am trying to get the users latitude and longitude.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class locationModule: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

func getLocation() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = (manager.location?.coordinate)!
    print(location.latitude)
    print(location.longitude)
    }
}
```

This is code is in a seperate Swift file, So I need `getLocation()` to be able to call `func locationManager`, how would I call the locationManager function from the getLocation() function.

Comment: Why would you want to call `locationManager`? The whole point is that it's called **for you** by the `CLLocationManager`

Comment: @AMomchilov What do you mean it's called by `CLLocationManager`

Comment: The whole point of `CLLocationManager` is for it to call `locationManager` method of your `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, in order to inform you of location changes. Calling that method yourself makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but it's not being called, probably because you didn't add the key to your Info.plist.

For your code, add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to your Info.plist, with a value such as `All your base are belong to us, so I use your location whenever I want.` as the String value.  Then just start your locationManager somewhere like `func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)` like this:

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?
var locMod:locationModule?

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    if ( locMod == nil )
    {
       locMod = locationModule()
    }
    locMod?.getLocation()
}
```

The first time, you will see the prompt, then you will see the location being logged.

FYI, here's how I organized the locationModule:

```
class locationModule: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    internal func getLocation() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }


    // MARK : CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol
    @objc
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        for location in locations {
            print("\(location.coordinate.latitude), \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
        }
    }
}
```